# React router v6, group routes by feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React router v6.

THE PROBLEM:

my `App.tsx` is very big as it includes routes for all of the application:

Ex.

```
 ...
 <Route path="products/" element={<ProductsList />} />
 <Route path="products/:slug" element={<ProductView />} />
... about 300 lines
```

I would like to group these routes by feature so that I end up having something like this:

```
 ...
 <Route path="admin" element={<AdminRoutes />} />
 <Route path="products" element={<ProductsRoute />} />
...
```

it would look cleaner and easier to read.

So far I have created something like this for the Admin section:

```
export const AdminRoutes = (): any => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="admin" element={<Admin />}>
       </Routes>
)}
```

and I have imported it like this inside `App.tsx`:

```
...
<Route element={<AdminRoutes />} path="admin" />
...
```

I am expecting to see the `<Admin />` component (defined in `AdminRoutes`), although I don't get any errors the screen is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const AdminRoutes = (): any => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="admin" element={<Admin />}>
       </Routes>
)}
```

Since you're using relative paths, the actual url that this will match is `/admin/admin`, one comes from the top level route in `App`, and another from here. Assuming you wanted this to only match "/admin", you can instead do:

```
<Route path="*" element={<Admin />}/> // Matches /admin
<Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}/> // Matches /admin/dashboard
```

Or you could use an absolute path:

```
<Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />}/>
<Route path="/admin/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}
```